# In Keras, is it possible to cluster the input data and then feed the data to different subnetworks depending on the cluster?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Basically, what I'm trying to do is:

- Perform some basic clustering, like K-means, of the input data.
- Get the cluster membership of the input samples.
- Train a separate deep neural network submodel for each cluster.

Below is a basic diagram of the idea. 
[image: Visualization of my idea]

Is it possible to do this by using a single keras model?

I've tried to do this using sklearn KMeans to separate my input data to clusters and then training a separate Keras model on each cluster, but this approach makes it difficult to calculate the test error later since I have to get the test error from each cluster and then manually calculate the overall error.

Comment: Probably you need to use separate model for each of your cluster inputs. But I think you can wrap the entire network in an outer model.

Comment: Wrapping the entire network in an outer model would be the ideal approach, but I don't know how to route the input to the correct network for the correct cluster, at least not elegantly. I want the input to be clustered, then automatically routed to the correct subnetwork which will calculate the output, all using one Keras network.

Comment: If you know you have a fixed number of clusters from the clustering algorithm (which you need because your model can't be dynamic), you can use a simple branching logic to route the inputs. But well, it's trickier because what do you do when you get different frequency of each cluster.

Comment: I will try to help you with some advice but I need to  know what is the output prediction feature?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you cluster the data to three groups and want to use a model to learn the different distribution of each group. I have some rough ideas.

1. You can let the cluster index be the label of each group and fit this label and your original goal at the same time. Like:

   output1 = Dense(cluster_numbers, activation='softmax')(x)

   output2 = Dense(output_dimensions, activation='softmax')(x)
2. Or if your data is clustered according to your original goal and they are mutually exclusive, you can also use a series of paratactic layers to output the results. But thsi will make your model very huge. Like:

   output = [Dense(output_dimensions, activation='softmax')(x) for _ in cluster_numbers]

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I didn't clarify my task well. The task that I'm trying to do is traffic flow prediction. What I wanted to do is to cluster the input data to basically get the category of the traffic density. Then, for different categories, I am predicting the future traffic flow using different neural networks.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So your task is that you have already get the cluster categories through a K-means model and using different models to predict traffic flow in each category. I think you should not be limited by a whole Keras model. You can fulfill your task like the training process as GAN. 1) Get a certain batch from generator. 2) Split it according to different categories. 3) Judge that and input the data to correct model. (use `model.train_on_batch()` function)

Comment: I was thinking about using multiple models as a last resort. The problem with that is I am using Keras callbacks to get the error of my model. However, to my understanding, if I am using different models for different clusters, I have to get the callbacks for each of the cluster's models and then manually calculate the overall error. I was wondering if it is possible to do it elegantly using one model.

Comment: In my opinions, if you want to use sub-models to calculate loss of each cluster respectively, your loss function must return a list of loss from all the sub-models because they are a whole calculation graph. If your loss function only returns one loss of either sub-model, it will be backpropagated to each sub-model which will cause an unwanted weights upgrade in those uncorrelated sub-models. This makes me fall into endless loops.